# Getting SQL query to select

Tags: mysql

Table: product: 
Attributes: pid, name

Table Name:item_product

Attributes: Itemid, @pid, length, price, colours.
 The pid is a foregin key from product

```
Itemid       pid            length          price    colour
1              1              3               5        blue
2              1              4               10        red
3              2              3               5         blue
4              2              6               20         green
5              3              4               4           g
6              4              3                3          r
7               1              3               4           e
8               1              4               6           r                   
9               2              6                100      light_blue
```

the pid is repeated thought out the database but the table above is a  small idea of what its like 
I want to select everything from length that related to the product id and its the colour

I have this query but its repeated

```
SELECT length, 
price FROM item_product WHERE pid=:id
```

if i run the query above and change pid to 1. it will just show me everything with pid 1 but i only want it to show it if its related to the  product `name` in the `product table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `INNER JOIN` like:

For example I have products named `Mouse`, `Keyboard`, `Monitor`, `Tablet` and `Hard Drive`.
And on my `Item_Product` table I have only items there for Mouse, Keyboard, Monitor and Tablet but not for `Hard Drive`. So, when I `INNER JOIN` the two tables Hard Drive will be excluded since it is not in `Item_Product` tables but although it is there in `Product` table.

```
SELECT Itemid, B.name, length, price, colour
FROM item_product A
INNER JOIN product B
ON A.pid = B.pid
```

Check my `sqlfiddle` [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b497/1)

And if you want to view specific product only then you could use the productid (pid) or name of the product like:

```
SELECT Itemid, B.name, length, price, colour
FROM item_product A
INNER JOIN product B
ON A.pid = B.pid
WHERE B.name = 'Mouse'
```

Example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b497/2)

If you want to understand more on `JOIN` check this [link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) it shows you the visual representation of how `JOIN` works in sql.

Comment: thanks for youe help this actually gave me an idea for something else :D much love for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following. I am using an **inner join**, to the table **product**, and added a **where** clause on the **name**.

```
SELECT pt.name,
length, 
price 
FROM item_product as pr
        inner join product  as pt on pt.pid = pr.pid
WHERE pr.pid = 1 and pt.name = 'name'
```

In the where clause, you need to filter by the name of your product. So change [name], to what you are after.

If you only would like to **filter by name only**, same query as above, but doing the **where** clause only on the name.

```
SELECT pt.name,
length, 
price 
FROM item_product as pr
        inner join product  as pt on pt.pid = pr.pid
WHERE  pt.name = 'name'
```

Let me know if this is what you are after.

Comment: thanks bro this gave me an idea of what I needed to do. Thanks